# Attach TCPDF to mail in Laravel

Tags: laravel, tcpdf

I want to attach pdf generated with tcpdf library without save.
I'm able to attach the pdf generated but it's corrupt.

I search a lot examples but any seems don't work

This my code:

```
public function index($id) {
    $viaje = Viaje::find($id);
    $users = User::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    // usersPdf is the view that includes the downloading content
    $view = \View::make('usersPdf', ['viaje' => $viaje, 'users' => $users]);
    $html_content = $view->render();
    // Set title in the PDF
    PDF::SetTitle("List of users");
    PDF::AddPage();
    PDF::writeHTML($html_content, true, false, true, false, '');

    //PDF::Output('userlist.pdf');
    $fileatt = PDF::Output($name='yourfilename.pdf', $dest='E');

    $pdf = chunk_split($fileatt);

    $contactopro = Contactoviajespro::find($id);

    $data = [
        'link' => 'http://',
        'contacto' => $contactopro->name,
    ];


    Mail::send('emails.notificacion', $data, function($msg) use($pdf) {
        $msg->from('administracion@buendialogistica.com', 'Javier');
        $msg->to('xavieeee@gmail.com')->subject('Notificación');

        $msg->attachData($pdf, 'orden.pdf');

    });

    return redirect()->route('home')
                    ->with(['message' => 'Email enviado correctamene']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "S" to generate pdf and do not do chunk_split(), Laravel will do that. Additionally, if you are using queue() instead of send(), it will fail because of the attachment. To queue, write a job and send with the job queue.